# Angular directives and the debugger

Tags: angularjs-directive, javascript-debugger

If I create an Angular directive:

```
App.directive('modalWindow', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            elem.draggable();
        }
    }  
});
```

and then reference it in markup:

```
    <div class="modalWindow">
```

and then place a breakpoint on `elem.draggable()`

will the debugger stop at the breakpoint when the app is run?

EDIT: It is not stopping in Visual Studio, hence my question.

Comment: Yes. I just tried on chrome. A breakpoint set inside returned link function pauses execution same as usual.

Comment: Thanks. To whoever downvoted: please see edit to my question. It's not stopping there in the Visual Studio debugger, so I don't know if that's a debugger issue, a problem in how I wired it up, or something else. I think it's a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the directive link function is being called?  Keep in mind that when you camel case the directive name ('modalWindow'), in the HTML, it needs to be snake-cased ('modal-window').  Since you're using a restriction on either element, attribute, or class ('EAC'), first make sure that your link directive is being called.  In your HTML, change this to

HTML

```
<div modal-window></div>
```

OR

```
<div class='modal-window'></div>
```

Try the debugger again and see if Visual Studio pauses now.

Comment: Thank you! The snake-cased detail really helped me out today!